# Passing a std::shared_ptr to a function object to std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr, functor

Need to have this Functor live as long as my thread does, so I've created a shared_ptr to it and trying to pass it to std::thread. I've copied the code and list of errors here.

```
struct Functor
{
    std::string greeting;
    explicit Functor(std::string _greeting="Hello!"): greeting { _greeting }     {}
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << greeting << "\n";
    }
};

auto main() ->int 
{
    std::shared_ptr<Functor> fp = std::make_shared<Functor> ();
    std::thread t(&fp);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

List of errors:

```
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'    std_threads C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr\xthread  240 
Error   C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found    std_threads C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\thr\xthread  240
```

I'm new to c++11 and concurrency. Please help me understand the following

1>does a std::thread always invoke the operator() inside an object when passed by value ? If so, why it has been defined so.

2>how to ensure that a resource given to a thread stays around as long as the thread does?

3>is the *Functor* written here, a function object ?

4>What have I done here in this code ?!

Comment: shouldn't it be `std::thread t(*fp)` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1>does a std::thread always invoke the operator() inside an object
>   when passed by value ? If so, why it has been defined so.

`std::thread` invokes `std::invoke`. From cppreference, if the first argument is neither a `pointer to member function` nor a `pointer to data member`; it is treated as a function object.
So, fp() will be called.

> INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) is equivalent to f(t1, t2, ..., tN) (that
>   is, f is a FunctionObject)

So you can basically do `std::thread t{*fp}`

> 2>how to ensure that a resource given to a thread stays around as long
>   as the thread does?

You can have `shared_ptr` to provide ownership of a shared object. Or you can just manually do it by ensuring the resource passed is in scope. The mileage varies.

> 3>is the Functor written here, a function object ?

Yes. A FunctionObject type is the type of an object that can be used on the left of the function call operator. However `fp` is not. But `*fp` is.

> 4>What have I done here in this code ?!

You can make it work by explicitly passing `Functor::operator()` with argument `fp.get()`. Ofcourse a simple way is to just pass `*fp`

[Demo](http://cpp.sh/72gwt)

Comment: thanks for your answer @themagiacalyang, but getting back on 3>what is a functor in c++, I have come across people saying an object that defines operator() is a functor or function object. 1>I will need to explore this further but I was able to do `std::thread((Functor()))` an it indeed prints `Hello!` without having to pass operator() explicitly.

Comment: @user3222 Yes. The demo was just for reference about how you can explicitly pass `operator()`. `Functor()` acts as a function object. In short f is a function object if you can do f(...) on it, where ... are the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`std::shared_ptr<Functor>` is not callable - it doesn't implement `operator()`, even while `Functor` does.

What's the purpose of `shared_ptr` here? Why not simply

```
int main() {
    Functor f;
    std::thread t(std::ref(f));
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

If for some reason you insist on having `Functor` instance managed by a `shared_ptr`, here's one way:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Functor> fp = std::make_shared<Functor> ();
    std::thread t([fp]() { (*fp)(); });
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still make `std::thread` take ownership of your smart pointer with this syntax:

```
std::shared_ptr<Functor> f = std::make_shared<Functor>();
std::thread thread (&Functor::operator(), f);
thread.detach();
```

If the first argument is a member function pointer, then the second argument is expected to be a reference or pointer to an instance of the class and `std::shared_ptr<Functor>` is accepted. When the thread finishes, the smart pointer will be deleted.

Downside: removes the benefit of having a functor because you have to specify the member function.